# Removing spaces for all the columns of a CSV file in bash/unix

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a CSV file in which every column contains unnecessary extra spaces added to it before the actual value. I want to create a new CSV file by removing all the spaces.

For example

One line in input CSV file

```
 123, ste hen, 456, out put
```

Expected output CSV file

```
123,ste hen,456,out put
```

I tried using awk to trim each column but it didn't work.

Comment: so can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo " 123, ste hen, 456, out put" | awk '{sub(/^ +/,""); gsub(/, /,",")}1'
123,ste hen,456,out put
```

Comment: But it can't handle _extra space**S**_ OP stated in the question at present form.

Comment: This will do it: `awk '{sub(/ +/,""); gsub(/ *, */,",")}1' test.in` . First the `sub` removes all the leading space on the record and the `gsub` handles spaces around commas. Record trailing space would need another `gsub` that could replace the first `sub` something like this: `gsub(/^ *| *$/,"")`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Thanks Claies/James this one worked for me. Thank you so much guys!

Comment: @stephenjacob This won't strip all unwanted spaces. Test with `echo " 123 , ste hen, 456, out put " | awk '{sub(/^ +/,""); gsub(/, /,",")}1' | cat -vte` to see remaining spaces. Then test same with my suggested `sed` i.e. `echo " 123 , ste hen, 456, out put " | sed -E 's/(^|,)[[:blank:]]+/\1/g; s/[[:blank:]]+(,|$)/\1/g' | cat -vte`

Answer (score 8):

This sed should work:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/(^|,)[[:blank:]]+/\1/g; s/[[:blank:]]+(,|$)/\1/g' file.csv
```

This will remove leading spaes, trailing spaces and spaces around comma.

**Update:** Here is an awk command to do the same:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*,[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS=, '{
  gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/, ""); $1=$1} 1' file
```

Comment: The `[[:blank:]]` character class is handy as it accommodate tabs

Comment: Yes it match Space or Tab but not newlines.

Comment: You may consider removing blank lines in the `sed` solution.

Comment: @sjsam why would you want to remove blank lines? I don't see any hint in the question that that'd be desirable.

Comment: @EdMorton : right ! Adding such an option is nbd anyway.

Comment: When I tried this the line `"Smith                     ","","Mr    ","123","  ","Main","St  ","  ","      ","        ","123 Main St",""` appears to be completely unchanged with all it's trailing spaces. I ran `head -10 sed9EdJiw`against the temp file while it's still in the process of writing. I'm new to linux. Is the content being fed the old file?

Comment: It is unchanged because this solution removes spaces after comma only.

Answer (score 5):

`awk` is your friend.

**Input**

```
$ cat 38609590.txt
Ted Winter, Evelyn Salt, Peabody
  Ulrich, Ethan Hunt, Wallace
James Bond, Q,  M
(blank line)
```

**Script**

```
$ awk '/^$/{next}{sub(/^[[:blank:]]*/,"");gsub(/[[:blank:]]*,[[:blank:]]*/,",")}1' 38609590.txt
```

**Output**

```
Ted Winter,Evelyn Salt,Peabody
Ulrich,Ethan Hunt,Wallace
James Bond,Q,M
```

**Note**

- This one removes the blank lines too - `/^$/{next}`.
- See the [[ awk ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) manual for more information.

Answer (score 4):

To remove leading blank chars with sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^|,) +/\1/g' file
123,ste hen,456,out put
```

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/(^|,) +/,"\\1","g")}1' file
123,ste hen,456,out put
```

With other awks:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^ +/,""); gsub(/, +/,",")}1' file
123,ste hen,456,out put
```

To remove blank chars before and after the values with sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/ *(^|,|$) */\1/g' file
123,ste hen,456,out put
```

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/ *(^|,|$) */,"\\1","g")}1' file
123,ste hen,456,out put
```

With other awks:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^ +| +$/,""); gsub(/ *, */,",")}1' file
123,ste hen,456,out put
```

Change  (a single blank char) to `[[:blank:]]` if you can have tabs as well as blank chars.

Comment: Thanks Ed for your help! I have learned how to use sed and awk now.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do with `awk` to remove multiple leading white-spaces is as below:-

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {s = ""; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$i);} 1' <<< "123, ste hen, 456, out put"
123,ste hen,456,out put
```

- `FS=OFS=","` sets the input and output field separator to `,`
- `s = ""; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)` loops across each column entry up to the end (i.e. from `$1`,`$2`...`NF`) and the `gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$i)` trims only the leading white-space and not anywhere else (one ore more white-space, note the `+`) from each column.

If you are want to do this action for an entire file, suggest using a simple script like below

```
#!/bin/bash
# Output written to the file 'output.csv' in the same path    

while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do   # Not setting IFS here, all done in 'awk', || condition for handling empty lines
   awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {s = ""; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$i);} 1' <<< "$line" >> output.csv
done <input.csv
```

Comment: There are shorter approaches than this, nice try though. When it comes to awk the general trend is to appreciate elegant idiomatic approaches.

Comment: @mona_sax: Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat > test.in
 123, ste hen, 456, out put
$ awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$i); print $0}' test.in
123,ste hen,456,out put
```

or written out loud:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=","                  # set the input field separator
  OFS=","                 # and the output field separator
}
{
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)     # loop thru every field on record
    gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$i) # remove leading and trailing spaces
  print $0                # print out the trimmed record
}
```

Run with:

```
$ awk -f test.awk test.in
```

Comment: If you use `-F' *, *'` then you don't need the loop, just 1 `gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")` and a field assignment `$1=$1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F' *, *' '$1=$1' OFS=, file_path
```

Answer (score -3):

You could try :

- your file :  ~/path/file.csv

`cat ~/path/file.csv | tr -d "\ "
sed "s/, /,/g" ~/path/file.csv`